Expectation of uniform distribution conditioned on an interval
I am trying to understand the concept of conditioning on an event better. To do so, I've cooked up the following toy problem then tried to generalize it in the context of uniform distribution.
Suppose $X$ is distributed uniformly on $[0,1].$ I want to compute $\mathbb{E}[X\vert I]$ where $I$ is the event that $X\in[0,1/4] \cup [3/4,1]$. Pretty sure I have applied the definitions correctly but any help in verification would be much appreciated!
My attempt: Writing $f$ to denote density,
$$f_{X\vert I}(x\vert I)= \frac{f_X(x)}{\int_I f_X(x)\,dx}=\frac{f_X(x)}{\int_0^{1/4} f_X(x)\,dx+\int_{3/4}^1 f_X(x)\,dx}=2 $$
The second equality follows from the fact that $[0,1/4]$ and $[3/4,1]$ are disjoint, and the third from the distribution of $X$.
By definition,
$$\mathbb{E}[X\vert I]=\int_I x\cdot f_{X\vert I}(x\vert I)\, dx=2\cdot \Bigg[\int_{0}^{1/4}x\,dx+\int_{3/4}^{1}x\,dx\Bigg]=\frac{1}{2}$$
Generalizing, suppose $J=I_1\cup I_2$ where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are disjoint and $J$ is a strict subset of $[0,1]$. Using a similar argument, I claim that
$$\mathbb{E}[X\vert J]=\frac{1}{\int_{I_{1}}dx+\int_{I_{2}}dx}\cdot\Bigg[\int_{I_1}x\,dx+\int_{I_2}x\,dx\Bigg]$$
Is my claim correct? Thanks in advance for your help!

Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki.

When you write $f_{X\mid I}(x\mid I) = 2$, it is generally assumed that $f_{X\mid I}(x\mid I)$ has value $2$ for every real number $x$.  But what you meant to state (or so I hope) is that $f_{X\mid I}(x\mid I)$ has value $2$ only when $x\in I$, and has value $0$ for $x \notin I$. The standard way to do this is to multiply the value $2$ by $\mathbf 1_I$, where $\mathbf 1_I$ is the indicator function of the set $I$, taking on value $1$ when $x\in I$ and value $0$ when $x\notin I$.

A generalization of this question is discussed and answered in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/525918/919.  The short answer is: use indicator functions.

$f_{X\vert I}(x)= \frac{1}{P(X\in I)}1_I(x)f_X(x)$.
